# How to package native prebuilts libraries for Android different platforms

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, cmake, android-ndk

For compiling native prebuilt libraries we use NDK toolchain with these two options `-DANDROID_ABI` and `-DANDROID_PLATFORM`, so in case if we support `android-28`, `android-29` platforms and `armeabi-v7a`, `arm64-v8a`, `x86`, `x86_6` ABIs we will have to sets of produced libraries:

```
.
├── android-28
│   ├── arm64-v8a
│   │   └── libMy.so
│   ├── armeabi-v7a
│   │   └── libMy.so
│   ├── x86
│   │   └── libMy.so
│   └── x86_64
│       └── libMy.so
└── android-29
    ├── arm64-v8a
    │   └── libMy.so
    ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   └── libMy.so
    ├── x86
    │   └── libMy.so
    └── x86_64
        └── libMy.so
```

We can easily use such obtained prebuilts in Android cmake, because it supports`${ANDROID_PLATFORM}` and `${ANDROID_ABI}` variables, e.g. `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
list(APPEND CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${THIRDPARTY_PREBUILT_DIR}/${ANDROID_PLATFORM}/${ANDROID_ABI}/mylib)
...
```

But packaging these prebuilts into APK seems not clear for me because `app/src/main/jniLibs` doesn't support platform hierarchy but only ABI:

```
.
└── jniLibs
    ├── arm64-v8a
    │   └── libMy.so
    ├── armeabi-v7a
    │   └── libMy.so
    ├── x86
    │   └── libMy.so
    └── x86_64
        └── libMy.so
```

And also the same structure in output `app-debug.apk/lib`.

So the **question**: Why do we have in toolchain and Android cmake options to differ platforms but packaging of native libraries (jni libraries) ignores them?

I use `Android Studio 3.6.3` with `Gradle 5.6.4`.

Comment: Do you need to have separate libraries for those two platform levels, or could you combine them into one library? If they really do need to be separate libraries, then you may want to build separate app bundles / APKs for different minimum API levels (see e.g. https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#flavor-dimensions).

Comment: @Michel: Thank you for the comment. I need to build some thirdparty libraries and then use them like prebuilts in Android app project, but for compiling them NDK toolchain requires that I specify ```-DANDROID_PLATFORM``` parameter but these libraries  don't depend on specific Android API (28 or 29 or whatever) only app needs to support 28 and 29. So I will do like @Dan Albert answered - will apply oldest version for compiling thirdparty libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose the platform as part of the build because that determines what devices your code will be compatible with. If you target 21, your code isn't guaranteed to run on anything older than Lollipop.

Apps are forward compatible though, so if you build for 21 you will run on Lollipop and everything after (with very rare exceptions, extremely rare as long as you stick to defined behaviors of public APIs). That's why you don't need to package the library for every platform, only the oldest you support.